# Docker Can't Find Install.sh

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created a folder in Windows that has a `Dockerfile` and an `install.sh` script. When I attempt to build the docker image, I get an error that says:

```
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN /install.sh                                                                                                                        0.6s
------
 > [4/4] RUN /install.sh:
#7 0.584 /bin/sh: 1: /install.sh: not found
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest  
ADD install.sh /
RUN chmod u+x /install.sh
RUN /install.sh
ENV PATH /root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

This is my install.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update  
apt-get upgrade -y  
apt-get install -y bzip2 gcc git ping htop screen vim wget  
apt-get clean  

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O Miniconda.sh
bash Miniconda.sh -b  
rm -rf Miniconda.sh  
export PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"  

conda install -y pandas  
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"

CMD ["/bin/zsh"]
```

This is what I am running in Windows to produce the error:

```
docker build -t app_test:v1.01 .
```

output:

```
[+] Building 1.3s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 158B                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 490B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [2/4] ADD install.sh /                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [3/4] RUN chmod u+x /install.sh                                                                                                                    0.5s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN /install.sh                                                                                                                        0.6s
------
 > [4/4] RUN /install.sh:
#7 0.584 /bin/sh: 1: /install.sh: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /install.sh]: exit code: 127
```

So far I've tried the following:

1. renaming the `install.sh` file to something else
2. Changing the `ADD` line to `COPY` so that the line says `COPY install.sh /install.sh`
3. googling the issue to see anyone else has experienced something
   similar.

EDIT #1:

`tree` and `ls` output:

```
PS C:\Users\Rick\Documents\experiments> tree
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is D49A-7235
C:.
No subfolders exist

PS C:\Users\Rick\Documents\experiments> ls

    Directory: C:\Users\Rick\Documents\experiments

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/21/2021 11:11 AM            132 Dockerfile
-a---          11/21/2021  9:05 AM            451 install.sh
```

EDIT #2 adding `RUN ls /` to `Dockerfile`:

```
[+] Building 2.0s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 181B                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 32B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] COPY install.sh /install.sh                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [3/5] RUN ls /                                                                                                                                     0.5s
 => [4/5] RUN chmod u+x /install.sh                                                                                                                    0.6s
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN /install.sh                                                                                                                        0.7s
------
 > [5/5] RUN /install.sh:
#9 0.694 /bin/sh: 1: /install.sh: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /install.sh]: exit code: 127
```

Comment: Could you please include your directory structure output via running `tree` in your project path?

Comment: @michael.grigoryan see EDIT #1

Comment: What do you see in the build output if you try to run ls on / ?

Comment: @LiorPollak see EDIT #2

Comment: Well seems like the file is not there. Try adding ./install.sh when you copy

Answer (score 4):

The cause of the issue was saving the `install.sh` file using Windows line endings.  It needed to be saved using Unix line endings.  In Visual Studio Code, change the "CRLF" button to "LF".

Comment: Glad that you were able to solve your issue